# Lifetime of Session Cookie

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, httpcookie

I have a question about the lifetime/behavior of a session cookie

The user opens siteA.com. An authentification cookie sessionAuth=xyz is set. The cookie is HttpOnly, Secure and Expires=Session.

[image]

siteA.com redirect to siteB.org by submitting a HTTP-Form, so the HttpMethod is POST.

siteB.org does some stuff and redirects back to siteA.com, also with HTTP-Form and HttpMethod=POST.
Should the browser now send the cookie sessionAuth=xyz with this HTTP-Request?

I did some tries with Chrome 86.0.4240.111 (64-Bit), unfortunately sometimes the cookie was added sometimes not. But I couldn't figure out when/why it worked and when not.

My thoughts:

- Yes, the cookie should be added because the browser was not yet closed, so the session is still valid.
- No, because the cookie is from siteA.com, but the HttpPost is done by siteB.com
- No, because the session is closed as soon the first redirect/form-submit happens.

What is the correct behavior?

I have the impression this worked in the past (Cookie available and added). Maybe the lastest cookie privacy changes have some impact? https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions.

Are SiteA.com and SiteB.com on the same domain ?

How you create your cookies ?

For me :

```
setcookie('admin_id', $result['admin_id'], time() + 28*24*3600, "/", null, false, true);
```

When we declare like that the cookies are valid in any part of the site.